# CakePHP 2.0 fetching Containable fields

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

```
'Tag' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'kannada',
        'MoviesTag' => array(
            'id' => '60',
            'movie_id' => '2',
            'tag_id' => '1'
        )
    )
)
```

I want to fetch Movie from movie_id of Tag in containable.. How to fetch that?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Tag` controller try something like this:

```
$this->Tag->find('all'); // this will return tag with movie detail
```

**OR**

if you want to use `Containable` behavior then try this:

```
$this->Tag->attach->behaviors('Containable');

$this->Tag->recursive = -1;

$this->Tag->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array('Tag.id', 'Tag.name'),
        'contain' => array(
                         'Movie'
                      )
));
```

Comment: In Movies controller i added that code.. How to call in Movies Controller.

Comment: @Sanganabasu you need to add this code within a method and then call that method. suppose you add the code in index method then hit the url then check the `print_r($results);`. check the update answer